# How to get a carousel with prev and next cut off

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I'd like to have a carousel slider that when you are on a smartphone, instead of getting the item alone and the nav arrows, you see a piece of the next item to slide and if course a piece of the prev item, if you are in a central position. See image below. [image]

This kind of style is very popular within mobile apps, cause it tells you "hey! there is something to slide here", so you don't need any arrow for example.

I've been using OWL Carousel 2, which is the definitive slider to me, it's simply perfect, but I can't get this effect to work. Perhaps I might need some css trick to break it a bit in order to show a small portion of the other items. But I don't want to override the dynamic values of width cause it breaks everything.

So if you guys know a carousel that is able to do that or a trick to get that effect, would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the problems? What doesn't work?

Comment: Now, let's say in the mobile, I get the item to slide that occupies exactly its own space... but I'd like to see a portion of the next and the prev one, like in the screenshot I posted above. So there aren't any issues, I just want to get this effect of seeing a portion of the besides items to slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution!

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html